# Is it possible to add "Sub-Headers/Columns" to a Material Table Table in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am creating a table for larger more complex data sets using react and the material-table library.
Is there a way to add sub-header/columns to the material-table?
So: title
title1 | title2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem few months ago. I only could achieve what I wanted by overriding the `Header` component of the `material-table`.

```html
components={{ Header: props => (
<TableHead {...props}>
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell rowSpan={2}> Column 1 </TableCell>
    <TableCell colSpan={2}> Column 2 </TableCell>
    <TableCell colSpan={2}> Column 3 </TableCell>
    <TableCell rowSpan={2}> Column 4 </TableCell>
    <TableCell rowSpan={2}> Action </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell> Column 2 A </TableCell>
    <TableCell> Column 2 B </TableCell>
    <TableCell> Column 3 A </TableCell>
    <TableCell> Column 3 B </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
</TableHead>
), }}
```

If you are using the editable material-table u should have a `tablecell` called `Action`.
And when you are inserting the columns it should be as usual. For example:

```js
columns = {
  [{
      field: "column1",
      title: "Column 1"
    },
    {
      field: "column2a",
      title: "Column 2 A"
    },
    {
      field: "column2b",
      title: "Column 2 B"
    },
    {
      field: "column3a",
      title: "Column 3 A"
    },
    {
      field: "column3b",
      title: "Column 3 B"
    },
    {
      field: "column4",
      title: "Column 4"
    },
  ]
}
```

You will have to style it using inline `css` and/or `makeStyles` (`material ui`) to make it look presentable.
Hope this helps. Please feel free to ask if you need more explainations.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! I have already overwritten the component as you have shown and it works ^^

Comment: so ur problem got solved? is there anything else u need me to help u with

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problems right now, but I'll get back to you if anything comes up. Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: @Aworthyprogrammer if this solved your problem don't forget to upvote and accept the answer

Comment: It seems that I am not allowed to upvote yet  ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Column Grouping](https://mui.com/components/tables/#column-grouping)

You can group column headers by rendering multiple table rows inside a table head:

```
<TableHead>
  <TableRow />
  <TableRow />
</TableHead>
```